# Eclipse PTD Symfony Plugin does not install

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, ubuntu-16.04

I try to Install the following plugin: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/symfony-plugin

To my eclispe Installation. But I get the error:

> ```
> Unknown Host: http://p2.pdt-extensions.org/content.xml
> p2.pdt-extensions.org
> ```

How can I fix this?

Note: My installation path of eclipce ptd is in /opt on Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

```
pcmagas@pcmagas-Lenovo-G70-70:/opt/eclipse/php-neon/eclipse$ ls -l
σύνολο 264
drwxrwxr-x 11 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Ιούλ  2 14:09 configuration
drwxrwxr-x  2 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Ιούν 24 19:22 dropins
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pcmagas pcmagas  80393 Ιούν  6 12:39 eclipse
-rw-rw-r--  1 pcmagas pcmagas    724 Ιούλ  2 11:44 eclipse.ini
-rw-rw-r--  1 pcmagas pcmagas  15551 Φεβ  27  2015 epl-v10.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pcmagas pcmagas 140566 Ιούν  6 12:39 icon.xpm
-rw-rw-r--  1 pcmagas pcmagas   6487 Φεβ  27  2015 notice.html
drwxrwxr-x  2 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Ιούν 24 19:22 plugins
drwxrwxr-x  2 pcmagas pcmagas   4096 Ιούν 24 19:22 readme
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in Eclipse:

```
1) Click Help > Install New Software...
2) IN Work with: click Add...
3) Enter Name: Symfony, Location: http://p2.pdt-extensions.org/
4) Click OK.
```

I think you had the wrong Location. There is no "content.xml" at the end.
Try this and see if it works.